# problem aligning equation to text

Tags: equations

I wrote this equation, and its width exceeds the column width, getting too big or misaligned with the text.
I'm using the model `\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}` on Overleaf.

```
{\footnotesize
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&-\frac{356826171875*X^{15} }{3487131648}+\frac{2235361328125*X^{14}}{178827264}\\
&-\frac{58964587890625*X^{13}}{83026944}+\frac{1907321917578125*X^{12}}{76640256}\\
&-\frac{5761142236515625*X^{11}}{9580032}+\frac{73927716089703125*X^{10}}{6967296}\\
&-\frac{430282659272096875*X^9}{3048192}+\frac{7809355955001431875*X^8}{5419008}\\
&-\frac{4403288984181213325*X^7}{387072}+\frac{120852046124572324475*X^6}{1741824}\\
&-\frac{6207399816840424359295*X^5}{19160064}+\frac{10882808072712485801413*X^4}{9580032}\\
&-\frac{10500573191548927169620429*X^3}{3632428800}+\frac{234212397492643035344441*X^2}{46569600}\\
&-\frac{5491059208260761344249*X}{1029600}+\frac{258753417707105253}{100}\
\end{aligned}
\label{3}
\end{equation}}
```

it was like in the image below

[image]

Comment: it helps people if you provide a complete document not just a fragment, but what answer do you want? Clearly the possibilities are, write it under the code block not by the side so it can be twice as wide, or use a smaller font, or use `\\ ` after the + so it is on more lines, or use a wider page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to introduce three additional line breaks. I would also visually separate the `X^{<i>}` terms from their coefficients. And, do use `\small` (for a 10% linear reduction in the font size) rather than `\footnotesize`; a 20% reduction of the font size may be a bit too extreme.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % use Times Roman for both text and math
\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text

\begin{document}

{\small % '\footnotesize' is a bit too extreme
\begin{equation}\label{3}
\addtolength\jot{3pt} % default value: 3pt
\begin{aligned}[b]
a &= 
 -\frac{356826171875}{3487131648}X^{15}
 +\frac{2235361328125}{178827264}X^{14}\\
&\quad-\frac{58964587890625}{83026944}X^{13}
 +\frac{1907321917578125}{76640256}X^{12}\\
&\quad-\frac{5761142236515625}{9580032}X^{11}
 +\frac{73927716089703125}{6967296}X^{10}\\
&\quad-\frac{430282659272096875}{3048192}X^9
 +\frac{7809355955001431875}{5419008}X^8\\
&\quad-\frac{4403288984181213325}{387072}X^7\\
&\qquad +\frac{120852046124572324475}{1741824}X^6\\
&\quad-\frac{6207399816840424359295}{19160064}X^5\\
&\qquad +\frac{10882808072712485801413}{9580032}X^4\\
&\quad-\frac{10500573191548927169620429}{3632428800}X^3\\
&\qquad +\frac{234212397492643035344441}{46569600}X^2\\
&\quad-\frac{5491059208260761344249}{1029600}X
 +\frac{258753417707105253}{100}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typesetting math intensive documents in two-column format is always a tough endeavor.

Resizing and adding a few line breaks seems the simplest way out for this case. However just doing `{\footnotesize<math material>}` is not the right method, because it would badly influence the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{resizemath}[1]{%
  % #1 = size changing command
  $$\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}#1%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
}{\end{minipage}$$}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayparameters}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{resizemath}{\footnotesize}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&-\frac{356826171875}{3487131648}X^{15}
 +\frac{2235361328125}{178827264}X^{14}\\
&-\frac{58964587890625}{83026944}X^{13}
 +\frac{1907321917578125}{76640256}X^{12}\\
&-\frac{5761142236515625}{9580032}X^{11}
 +\frac{73927716089703125}{6967296}X^{10}\\
&-\frac{430282659272096875}{3048192}X^9
 +\frac{7809355955001431875}{5419008}X^8\\
&-\frac{4403288984181213325}{387072}X^7
 +\frac{120852046124572324475}{1741824}X^6\\
&-\frac{6207399816840424359295}{19160064}X^5\\
& +\frac{10882808072712485801413}{9580032}X^4\\
&-\frac{10500573191548927169620429}{3632428800}X^3\\
&+\frac{234212397492643035344441}{46569600}X^2\\
&-\frac{5491059208260761344249}{1029600}X
 +\frac{258753417707105253}{100}
\end{split}
\label{3}
\end{equation}
\end{resizemath}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the number at the bottom, add the `tbtags` option to `amsmath`. If I do

```
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
```

the same code as above would produce

[image]

**Note.** This doesn't break the recommendation to never use `$$` inside the `document` environment. Here I use `$$` knowing what it does, which is what we need for the particular case, namely isolating the font size changing command inside the `minipage`.